# Можно ли одновременно вернуть данные вместе с заголовками ответа используя Retrofit 2?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Есть такой сервис:

```
interface AuthService {

    @Headers("api: 0.0.1")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("do-login")
    fun login(
            @Field("login") login: String,
            @Field("pass") pass: String
    ): Observable<UserData>

}
```

Так я делаю запрос:

```
authService.login("test","1111")
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe ({
                    user ->
                    Log.v("Result")
                }, { error ->
                    error.printStackTrace()
                })
```

Таким образом в `user` у меня содержится `UserData`. Но, мне нужно еще и заголовки ответа (response headers) получить как-то, чтоб было что-то вроде этого:  `(user, response) -> ...`

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте тип возвращаемый указать Response<ResponseBody> - тогда в `onNext` должен прийти вся инфа, включая заголовки

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, почти правильно, то что я хотел будет так выглядеть: ` Observable<Result<UserData>>`

Answer (score 2):

`Observable<UserData>` нужно заменить на `Observable<Result<UserData>>`